# value() and nodes() method in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, xquery, xquery-sql

Here is my code

```
DECLARE @dataModel XML
SET @dataModel =
   '<object name = "cardApplication" type = "businessObject" mainTableSchema = "card" mainTableName = "application" >
    <components>
    <component name = "get">
    </component>
    </components>  
    </object>'
SELECT b.value('../../@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS objectName,
       b.value('@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS actionName
FROM @dataModel.nodes('/object/components/component') AS a(b)
```

Here the output I get is 
objectName = cardApplication and actionName = get.

I'm new to xquery and wonder how the objectName is returned from this piece of line :

```
"b.value('../../@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS objectName"
```

and why not this :

```
"b.value('../@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS objectName"
```

I thought since the 'name' field in root element I can use '..@/name', but its give me NULL. 
someone please explain what does '../../' shorthand used for/ how to use it? any links to understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `..` effectively means go back one level. The alias `b` is refering to the level `/object/components/component`. So, if you go back one level (using a single `..`) you end up at the node `components` (specifically `/object/components`). Thus with `b.value('../@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)')` you would be trying to return the value of `name` for the `components` node; which it doesn't have.

Thus, to get back to the `object` node, you need to go back 2 levels, which means using `../../`.

The idea is identical to if you were in command line. For example `C:\Windows\System32> ls ..\..` would list the contents of `C:\` in Windows, or `larnu@desktop:/var/opt/mssql$ ls ../..` would list the contents of `/var` in Unix.

Comment: Thanks much. Perfect explanation i needed.

Comment: If it answers your question @Mar1009, please do mark it as the solution. It'll help others if they have the same question and see that a correct answer has been given.